# Right-align LoF entries

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

Is there a simple way to align the RHS of LoF entries; for example using hyphenation, sloppy spacings, or similar?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\overfullrule=10mm

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@tocrmarg}{3em}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\microtypesetup{protrusion=false}
\listoffigures
\microtypesetup{protrusion=true}

\begin{figure}
\caption{2D anisotropic velocity model used for objective function analysis anisotro\-pic}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{2D anisotropic velocity model used for objective function analysis 2D anisotropic velocity model used for objective function analysis 2D anisotropic velocity model used for objective function analysis}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What about adding `\hyphenation{...}` to your preamble, which defines the default hyphenation points for `anisotropic`? For example, using `\hyphenation{ani-so-tro-pic}`.

Comment: `\hyphenation{\ldots}` certainly helps with the second LoF entry for the example above, thank you @Werner; however it makes no change to the first entry, where `anisotropic` is the last word of the line. Is there a way to override this?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you have to play around a bit with the parameters you have. In the following example, making the box for the page number bigger gives a good result, but it make things worse for the next entries. In such a case, your only chance of getting a good result is to take things into your own hands and change the text a bit.

[image: hdebensLofEntryAlign]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}

\overfullrule=10mm

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\@pnumwidth{2.55em}
\makeatother

\hyphenation{an-iso-tro-pic}
\begin{document}

\microtypesetup{protrusion=false}
\listoffigures
\microtypesetup{protrusion=true}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{2D anisotropic velocity model used for objective
    function analysis anisotropic}
    \caption{2D anisotropic velocity model used for objective
    function analysis 2D anisotropic velocity model used for
objective function analysis 2D anisotropic velocity model used
for objective function analysis}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```